# Centralized solution to manage iptables rules on multiple machines

Tags: iptables

Is there any open-source solution to manage iptables rules on multiple machines across a network from one single centralized management point?

Comment: Not sure why this Q has been downvoted, it's relevant for me.

Answer (score 1):

These seem nice:

Puppet iptables module:
https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-iptables

Firewall builder:
http://www.fwbuilder.org/